# Get WordPress Posts Where Two Different Custom Fields Are The SAme

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get a list of posts where two custom fields have the same values. I'm not using Advanced Custom Fields.

Currently, I have this:

```
        <?php    
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'close_answer_1',
                    'value' => $close_answer_1,
                    'compare' => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'answer',
                    'value' => $close_answer_1,
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            )
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
```

This is going on a POST single page.

The result of the close_answer_1 custom field is `INSET`

And I'm trying to get any other post where `answer`, the custom field is equal to `INSET`

Answer (score 0):

Change `'relation' => 'OR',` to `'relation' => 'AND',` and that will bring all the post that has both same answer in both meta keys.

Comment: That didn't work for some reason. I also tried to change the second $close_answer_1 to $answer, that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the values you have from the database that confirm it should bring back something?

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty standard, as follows. You need the relation set to "AND"

And if it doesn't work, either your keys are wrong, or your value isn't set?

If you `var_dump()` your result, you could get a closer look.

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'close_answer_1',
        'value'   => $yourValue,
        'compare' => '=',
        'type'    => 'CHAR',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'answer',
        'value'   => $yourValue,
        'compare' => '=',
        'type'    => 'CHAR',
    ),
);
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'nopaging'               => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
    'meta_query'             => $meta_query
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Not sure this is right still. Maybe I'm not helping... I'm trying to compare two different keys that may have the same value. So, across all posts—the two keys are close_answer_1 and answer... and their two values should match to get the 1 related post.